# I can't conect to my R610 iDRAC web interface

Tags: networking, dell, dell-poweredge, local-area-network, drac

I'm a complete networking idiot and I've fallen at the first hurdle.

I have an R610 here, just hooked it all up and powered it on. Checked the iDRAC settings (made sure it was using the shared NIC, as I don't have switch space to go dedicated).

The IP address stated in the iDRAC settings is the default static 192.168.0.120.
The IP address set in the R610 UEFI is set to 'Dynamic - DHCP'.

When I check the connected devices at my router page, I can only see the servers mac address, connected at 192.168.0.50. If I change the server to a static IP, it remains at .50. If I set the iDRAC to dynamic, I still can't see it connecting to my router, and the server remains on .50.

Whatever I do, I can't access the iDRAC web interface via 192.168.0.120 nor 192.168.0.50.

Added information  from second account of OP

The subnet is the same. 255.255.255.0.

I am OP, though I posted the question as guest. For some reason it wouldn't let me comment thereafter.

Some more info:

If I set both the iDRAC to DHCP and the R610 (via lifecycle controller) to iDRAC, neither show their assigned IPs in the interface. If I check the connected devices to my router, it still only shows the first NIC port connected, at 192.168.0.50.

So DHCP will assign the mainboard an IP, but not iDRAC.

Comment: What are the ip address settings of the machine you're trying to connect FROM? IP address/subnet mask?

Comment: The IP for my desktop is assigned by DHCP on 192.168.0.X. Not sure on the subnet. I'm assuming the solution to my problem is extremely simple and I'm just missing something, pretty sure its on the R610 end.

Comment: You should _become_ sure about the subnet.

Comment: the subnet is the same,. 255.255.255.0. I am OP, though I posted the question as guest. For some reason it wouldn't let me comment thereafter. Some more info: If I set both the iDRAC to DHCP and the R610 (via lifecycle controller) to iDRAC, niether show their assigned IPs in the interface. If I check the connected devices to my router, it still only shows the first NIC port connected, at 192.168.0.50. So DHCP will assign the mainboard an IP, but not iDRAC.

Comment: the subnet is the same. both the desktop and the server are connected via ethernet to the router. if I had to guess, the issue lies somewhere with my configuration of the iDRAC. it is set to shared, do both the server and the IDRAC therefore need the same IP? DHCP refuses to assign an IP to the iDRAC even if it's set to DHCP.